# iOS: Only Airpods connect directly to answering call. For other company headphone, you have to select bluetooth after answering

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession, airpods

I was recently working on a iOS calling app. Suddenly, one of my colleagues informed me that his headphone is not connecting to call directly after answering though his headphone is connected to bluetooth . However, one of my other colleagues, airpods are connecting to bluetooth. He did not have to select bluetooth after answering. Is it true for all the non apple products? If yes, is only apple headphones get this extra facility.

Answer (score -1):

Apple devices will connect to AirPods automatically when placed in ears. Android devices will need to pair them in Bluetooth. When calling, it depends on the device settings what the default speaker is.

Comment: All the device, I am talking about are iphone and bluetooth is already connected with those device.